# Laravel eloquent postgress copy from csv query

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, pdo

I want to copy data from csv to postgress running following sql query:

```
DB::statement("\COPY marketo.leads FROM '/home/mark/dw_files/tests/leads.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;");
```

And I get the error :

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"
>   LINE 1: \COPY marketo.leads FROM '/home/mark/dw_files/tests/leads.cs...
>           ^ (SQL: \COPY marketo.leads FROM '/home/mark/dw_files/tests/leads.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;)
>
> Caused by
>    PDOException: SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"
>    LINE 1: \COPY marketo.leads FROM '/home/mark/dw_files/tests/leads.cs...
>            ^

Although when I run this query in psql it works ok.

Comment: That's a psql command, not PDO or pgsql_* - you will need to load the csv file into an array, then insert from there.

Comment: Strangely when I grant superuser and use copy it works.Does  it means that copy is pgsql command and \copy not?